# Error in initializing AnimationController in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make animated icon but I have an error in `AnimationConroller _controller` line, before I write any code for Icons. Here is the code:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _controller;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController();
  }

Comment: Is the error message `Non-nullable instance field 'controller' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or a generative constructor that initializes it, or mark it 'late'.` or is it regarding something else?

Answer (score 0):

From around July 2020 Dart was becoming null safe. After that we can't keep variables uninitialized without explicitly specifying that they could be null or that they would be initialized later.

## Solution 1 - Using `late` keyword

Replace `AnimationController _controller` with `late AnimationController _controller`

Late variables are used in two situations as per [Dart documentation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables) :

> - Declaring a non-nullable variable that’s initialized after its declaration.
> - Lazily initializing a variable.

## Solution 2 - Using `?` operator

`?` is called Operational spread operator in category of Null check operators

Replace `AnimationController _controller` with `AnimationController? _controller;`

`?` essentially means that a given variable can be `null` or have some other value as per its data type.

Example :

`Color? favoriteColor` means `favoriteColor` will either be `null` or have some appropriate value.

## Solution 3 - using both `late` keyword and `?` operator

Replace `AnimationController _controller` with `late AnimationController? controller`

For more information about Null Safety :

- [Null-Safety Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYhOU9AuaFs)
- [Null-Safety and late keyword explained with examples](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety)

For more information about `late` keyword:

- [Late keyword](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#late-variables)